# Java Process get result

Tags: java

I am currently working on voice recognition project and I want to access certain keys based on user's voice commmand. For example If a user speaks 'a', I want to print a. I found a cmd command that does this work. This command works fine in command prompt and returns a as output. But i want to use this in my java application. I found a method that can fetch command output  and prints it. But in this case it is not able to print 'a'. Please help..Here is the code snippet.

```
public void Voice() throws IOException {
   Process p;
   String work = "cmd /c nircmd.exe sendkey a press"; // used nircmd utility

   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(work);
   String output="";
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

   while ((output = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
       System.out.println(output);
   }

   reader.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run Windows' command `cmd` from Java, keep in mind that your working directory is your project directory or the directory from where you run `java`. So from the symptoms you have described, it seems that when you run the `nircmd` utility from java, it is not found. Try giving a full path to the exe.

Replace

`String work = "cmd /c nircmd.exe sendkey a press";`

with

`String work = "cmd /c "c:\\your-path\\nircmd.exe sendkey a press";`

Comment: The process is working fine but not returning output 'a'. As nircmd utility is in Windows folder. So it scans windows folder first and there is no need to provide the full path....